# Select Path & Delete From Shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency

I'm a bit stuck, I have my illustrator file with a design for my logo and I need to remove a part of the shape.

For example, there is a square with a smaller square inside it but the smaller square needs to be removed so there is a hole in the bigger square that the background can penetrate through so it can be exported with transparency and look normal.

How would I do this as I've not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select both squares, go to 'Window → Pathfinder' and click the 'Minus Front' (second) button. Also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy4Q-N8jHPQ) about this.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the answer and the quick response too!

Answer (score 0):

The shapebuilder tool can be used for this purpose.

Select the tool and press Alt to remove a shape.